# Mergesort output changes when printf is used

Tags: c, debugging, printf, output, mergesort

While trying to craft up a mergesort in C as an exercise, I am encountering a weird issue where the output of the algorithm changes with the presence of a printf. Let me elaborate it further. I have a "MergeSort.h" file in which I have my mergesort algorithm as follows:

```
#ifndef _MSORT_H_
#define _MSORT_H_

void merge(int a[],int lo,int mi,int hi){
    int n1 = (mi - lo) +1;
    int n2 = hi - mi;
    int left[n1];
    int right[n2];
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    for(i = 0;i < n1;i++){
        left[i] = a[lo+i];
    }
    for(j = 0;j < n2;j++){
        right[j] = a[mi+j+1];
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for(k = lo;k <= hi;k++){
        if(left[i] < right[j]){
            a[k] = left[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }else{
            a[k] = right[j];
            j = j+1;
        }
    }

}

void msorthelper(int a[],int p,int r){
    if(p < r){
        int mid = (p + r)/2;
        msorthelper(a,0,mid);
        msorthelper(a,mid+1,r);
        merge(a,p,mid,r);
    }
}

void msortex(int a[],int size){
    msorthelper(a,0,size-1);
    int counter;
    for(counter = 0;counter < size;counter++){
        printf(" %d ",a[counter]);
    }
}
#endif
```

I have my corresponding sort tester in sorttester.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mergesort.h"

int main(){

    int out[] = {8,1,6};
    msortex(out,3);

}
```

The output from running the sorttester is as follows:

> 1  0  0

Now here's the interesting part, when I put any printf statement to the beginning of the merge, the correct output is generated. Here's an example:

```
    #ifndef _MSORT_H_
    #define _MSORT_H_

    void merge(int a[],int lo,int mi,int hi){
        printf("Hello\n"); 
        int n1 = (mi - lo) +1;
        int n2 = hi - mi;
        int left[n1];
        int right[n2];
        .................Rest of the code.....
```

The output now is:

> HelloHello 1  6  8

This is the correct sorted order for the array 8 6 1.

Can somebody tell me what I might be doing wrong here that is causing the output to be drastically by the presence of a printf?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your merging part of code:

```
for(k = lo;k <= hi;k++){
    if(left[i] < right[j]){
        a[k] = left[i];
        i = i + 1;
    }else{
        a[k] = right[j];
        j = j+1;
    }
}
```

Lets assume that

```
left[] = {1, 2}
right[] = {3, 4, 5}
```

After 2 iterations of your merging loop (k) the value of "i" will be 2. From now on, you will try to compare

```
left[2] < right[j]
```

Which is invalid, as left[2] will refer to some random memory (left array size is only 2, so element of index 2 doesnt exist, only 0 and 1)

So, if you add guards for the i and j values, for example by changing first if condition to:

```
if(i != n1 && (j == n2 || left[i] < right[j])){
```

You should be fine.

Anyway, I should also tell you that you shouldnt declare array sizes with values that are not const, like:

```
int left[n1];
int right[n2];
```

Its actually forbidden by standard. You should either allocate it dynamically, use vectors(if c++) or jus declare them global with large enough size (maximum n value)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with the merge, but do you by any chance know why the presence of the printf is causing the output to be correct?

Comment: Although I cannot be sure what compiler does, I can suggest you making a little test. add this printf before loop with 'k' `printf("ns1: %d, ns2: %d\n",n1, n2);` and this one after(inside) the loop `printf("left[%d]: %d, right[%d]: %d\n", i, left[i], j, right[j]);`. Now, if you run it without the hello print, the value of right[1](out of bound) will be 0 - most likely just fresh memory. Thus why 0 is compared to 8 and is selected in favor to 8. On the other hand, if you run Hello printf, it most likely allocates some temporary memory, thus causing right[1] to be 32767 and thus 8 is selected.

Comment: If your machine doesn't show you any difference in those values, you can take a look at my output: https://gist.github.com/kareth/782c8197485cd5f50c9b

Comment: Seems like this is a compiler quirk. Thanks for pointing out the issue. I am marking this as the answer.